# Custom divider between 2 minipage and lstlisting

Tags: listings, verbatim, minipage

I am using the following code to have 2 boxes beside each other for code comparison:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{singlespace}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML,frame=lrtb]
%one
  %two
    Hi there
\end{lstlisting}%
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML,frame=lrtb]
<one>
  <two>
    Hi there
  </two>
</one>
\end{lstlisting}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following being rendered:

[image: 1]

I would like to place custom text between the 2 boxes. Ideally, something that looks like:

[image: 2]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please extend your code to a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (including `\documentclass` `\begin{document}` etc. that illustrates your problem. This makes it easier for others to use your code as a basis to help you!

Comment: Could you state your exact requirements? Simply changing `\hfill` with the text would do it. Do you want line breaking ability? Should the boxes never go beyond the official textwidth, etc.? You can just place a third `minipage` between the two.

Answer (score 3):

As Martin said, you can use another `minipage` with with a `fbox` and `parbox` to enable line breaking.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings,setspace,amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{singlespace}
\begin{minipage}[r]{0.38\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML,frame=lrtb]
%one
  %two
    Hi there
\end{lstlisting}%
\end{minipage}%
\hfil
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.17\textwidth}
\centering
\fbox{
\parbox[m]{.8\textwidth}{\centering Renders $\implies$}}
\end{minipage}%
\hfil
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.38\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML,frame=lrtb]
<one>
  <two>
    Hi there
  </two>
</one>
\end{lstlisting}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

[image]